# PayFast md5 Hash Generator

Tags: node.js, md5

I am testing a pay cart with Payfast. One thing they require is a signature which is a md5 hash based on, I quote:

> A security signature of the transmitted data taking the form of an MD5 hash of the submitted variables.
>
> The string from which the hash is created, is the concatenation of the
>   name value pairs of all the non-blank variables with ‘&’ used as a
>   separator eg. name_first=John&name_last=Doe&email_address=… where
>   pairs are listed in the order in which they appear on this page.
>
> This hash will be regenerated by the PayFast engine and the values
>   compared to ensure the integrity of the data transfer.

I have tested my string in the Payfast sandbox and I am getting the identical string. When I create the md5 hash in the sandbox, it all works perfectly.

When I generate the hash in node I get a different hash. I have tried using:

crypto, md5-hash, blueimp-md5, and salted-md5 with and without the passphrase (secret) but never get the same md5 hash that is generated in the Payfast sandbox environment.

I have tried:

```
let saltedHash = md5(value, "Perfectstuff123");
let saltedHash = saltedMd5(value, "Perfectstuff123");
```

with value being the string(I am pretty sure it is correct as I have compared my node string with the string in the sandbox) and "Perfectstuff123" being the passphrase or secret that needs to get salted.

I am not sure if its a utf-8 or utf-16 or something else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `CrtyoJS.MD5(value).toString()`?? Where value is the urlencoded string with the passphrase if you have one set.